# Selecting features in ArcMap continuously?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

My task is to select some of the features in a layer so that the whole area of them can be near to a particular value. While I got trouble when using select tools in ArcMap 10.6.

[image]

[image]

For example I want to select the features in the pics above in the same time, while I don't know how to select them continuously, since when I select the features on the top and the selections of features under will disappear. I try to press ctrl as it works in Excel while it doesn't work in ArcMap.

Comment: You are doing select by attribute? If so then use parameter ADD_TO_SELECTION. Is it the case? 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm

Comment: Try shift key instead of ctrl

Answer (score 3):

Even a better way than holding the Shift key on the keyboard, would be to change the Selection behavior in ArcMap. By default, each time you click on features it creates a new selection. You can go to the Selection menu and change the Interactive Selection Method for multiple choices:

- Add to current selection (continuously adds to a current selection; requires you use the Clear Selection tool to clear the selected features).
- Remove from current selection (continuously removes features from what you have selected)
- Select from the current selection (self-explanatory).
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are selecting features interactively and want to select multiple contiguous (or non-contiguous) features at one time, use the **shift** key while clicking.

See [Selecting Features Interactively](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/selecting-features-interactively.htm) for more information.